# Compute Quick Xor Hash in C# for OneDrive

Tags: c#, .net, hash, onedrive, xor

I am trying to create a method which compute the quick xor hash of local files to compare with the quick xor hash of One Drive.

[How to compute OneDrive XOrHash in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650931/how-to-compute-onedrive-xorhash-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

i have followed the link above but still the hash is not matching with the one i am getting from One Drive.

the hash i am generating is - "7LdTRDjeIdozPowImIrWicDTRg" and the one i got from one drive is - "aNkVDMEUxODg5QjdDRDY3QyE1NjEuMg"

does anyone have any idea what am i missing? TIA

Comment: Can u share your code? Hard to guess.

Comment: `public static string HashGenerator(string path)
{
using (var quickXor = new QuickXorHash())
{
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
byte[] bytes = quickXor.ComputeHash(stream);
return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}
}
}`

Comment: one drive personal hash changed? 
as mentioned in this
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/hashes?view=odsp-graph-online)
OD personal don't support quickxor hash but the hash i am getting from the one drive is in quick xor format.
am i doing this wrong?